# How to calculate the volume of an "icecream cone"?

Tags: geometry, volume

How to calculate the volume of this shape?

[image]

I've tried to do $2.5\cdot 2.5\cdot 3.14\cdot 12$ and then divide that with $3$ since the first part is a cone. But I only get $78.5$ by doing that. Am I missing a part or what? I'm confused.

Comment: The volume of a cone is $1/3\cdot \text{Area(base)} \cdot \text{height}$

Comment: Your calculation looks correct to me. I can't find any mistakes, assuming that the shape is a cone.

Comment: Well I know that, I said that I tried dividing with three.. Am I doing something wrong with my current calculation? EDIT to Johanna: That's strange..

Comment: Is $12 cm$ the height of the cone or the slant height?

Comment: Is this just a cone? Or is it a cone resting on a sphere?

Comment: To Jimmy: It may be the length of the slant height but I don't know, if you try both ways can you come up with the answer 110 cm^3 somehow?

Comment: Perhaps you should show a picture of the question.

Comment: To Bot: First of this isn't even in the algebra section of my book.. second of I'm really just trying to get help to understand what I did wrong..

Comment: To Mike: Yeah I'll photo it, I must've made the picture look dumb or something.

Comment: Bot: This is a perfectly fine question. OP's tried to do it, showed us his/her work, and asked for help. This is a legitimate use of Math.SE.

Comment: I can see that I didn't remember the assignment completely, so I drew a bit wrong I think. Now you have the right picture.

Comment: find volume of semisphere + cone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be an "ice-cream cone"

$$\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{3}\pi(2.5)^2\cdot\underbrace{\sqrt{12^2-2.5^2}}_{\text{height of cone}}}_{\text{cone part}} + \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{4}{3}\pi(2.5)^3}_{\text{semisphere}}  \approx 109.54141$$

I only now noticed the new picture. In this picture the height of the cone is **given** as $12cm$. In this case it works out to about $111cm$. Did the question specify to round to the nearest $10cm$?

Comment: I actually just noticed that trying to calculate this and no, the question didn't specify to round to the nearest 10cm. I got the answer to actually be 111.2 cm^3 .. it's pretty strange.

Comment: However checking at the answers for the previous questions, it does seem like the answers are fairly rounded down or up so I think that's the case here too. Thank you for all your insightful help!

Comment: This is assuming the height given (12) is the slant height. I don't know what's supposed to be implied by the picture.